# Issue Creating Text File Via Visual Basic (Not writing text)

Tags: vb.net, text-files

```
Private Sub Button1_Click(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles Button1.Click

    Dim FILE_NAME As String = "C:\KVRequest.txt"
    Dim aryText(4) As String

    aryText(0) = "TextBox4.Text"
    aryText(1) = "TextBox5.Text"
    aryText(2) = "TextBox6.Text"
    aryText(3) = "TextBox7.Text"
    aryText(4) = "TextBox8.Text"

    Dim objWriter As New System.IO.StreamWriter(FILE_NAME, True)

    objWriter.Close()
    MsgBox("Text file created in your C drive, attach this file in an email to someone@gmail.com Please check that all of the details are correct before sending.")

End Sub
```

What I am trying to do is get the text from the text boxes (4 5 6 7 8) to write into a text file. The code I have creates the file, but does not write text into it, can anyone give me a tip on how to get this working?

Thanks!

Edit: Also while I am here, I was trying to get it so button_1.enabled was only true if all of the text boxes had been edited, but I could not think of a practical way to do this, if you could help me with this I would also be very grateful!

Comment: Please post a **minimal** (but *complete*) code that has been stripped of everything that is not immediately relevant to the problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Given the code posted above, the reason nothing is being written to the file is because you're not telling it to write anything to the file.  You would need to add something like this between the creation of your `StreamWriter` and where you close the close method on it:

```
objWriter.WriteLine(TextBox4.Text)
objWriter.WtiteLine(TextBox5.Text)
etc...
```

Also, the simplest option for only enabling the save button is to create a [Control.TextChanged](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.control.textchanged.aspx) handler for each of your text boxes (or use the one Sub to do it for all of them by adding all their events to the one handler method) and have it do something similar to:

```
If TextBox4.Text <> "" And TextBox5.Text <> "" And TextBox6.Text <> "" Then
    Button1.Enabled = True
Else
    Button1.Enabled = False
End If
```